# Optimizing a CUDA kernel with irregular memory accesses

Tags: c++, c, cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I have the following CUDA kernel which seems very "tough" to optimize:

```
__global__ void DataLayoutTransformKernel(cuDoubleComplex* d_origx, cuDoubleComplex* d_origx_remap, int n, int filter_size, int ai )
{
    for(int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; idx < filter_size; idx+=blockDim.x * gridDim.x)
    {
        int index = (idx * ai) & (n-1);
        d_origx_remap[idx] = d_origx[index];
    }
}

//Parameters were defined before
int permute[loops] = {29165143,3831769,17603771,9301169,32350975, ...}
int n = 33554432;
int filter_size = 1783157;

for(int i=0; i<loops; i++)
{
    DataLayoutTransformKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock, 0, stream[i]>>>((cuDoubleComplex*) d_origx,(cuDoubleComplex*)d_origx_remap+i*filter_size, n, filter_size, permute[i]);

}
```

The purpose of the kernel is to reorder the data layout of `d_origx[]` from irregular to regular (`d_origx_remap`). The kernel is launched several times with different access strides (`ai`).

The challenge here is the irregular memory access pattern in referring the array of `d_origx[index]`. My idea was to use shared memory. But for this case it seems very hard to use shared memory to coalesce global memory access.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to optimize this kernel?

Comment: Maybe you can hide some of the latency by launching the kernel that processes the remapped buffers concurrently with the transform kernel in a staggered way. 1st iteration is only the remapping kernel. Second iteration concurrently launches the remapping kernel and a kernel that processes the results from the first remapping, etc. Maybe also look into rolling this functionality directly into the next kernel (have the kernel pull its values out at strided locations).

Answer (score 5):

The Trove library is a CUDA/C++ library with support for AoS support, and likely gives close to optimal performance for random AoS access. From the GitHub page it looks like trove will get about 2x over the naive approach for 16-byte structures.

https://github.com/BryanCatanzaro/trove

[image: Random access performance using Trove compared to the naive direct access approach]

Comment: Just mention that Trove works for compute capability `3.0` and above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do much to optimize your code.

There is not at all thread cooperations, so I would say that shared memory is not the way to go.

You may try changing

```
__global__ void DataLayoutTransformKernel(cuDoubleComplex* d_origx, cuDoubleComplex* d_origx_remap, int n, int filter_size, int ai)
```

to

```
__global__ void DataLayoutTransformKernel(const cuDoubleComplex* __restrict__ d_origx, cuDoubleComplex* __restrict__ d_origx_remap, const int n, const int filter_size, const int ai)
```

i.e., using the `const` and `__restrict__` keywords. Particularly `__restrict__` will enable `nvcc` to perform some optimizations, see Section B.2 of the CUDA C Programming Guide. For the Kepler architecture, the `const` and `__restrict` keyword may be tagged by the compiler to be loaded through the Read‐Only Data Cache, see the [Kepler architecture whitepaper](http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/kepler/NVIDIA-Kepler-GK110-Architecture-Whitepaper.pdf).